# Matlab - how to replace all the special characters in a vector?

Tags: regex, matlab, vector

Is it possible to replace all the special characters in a matlab vector through a regular expression?

Thank you

**EDIT: **

Thank you for your responses. I'm trying to achieve the following. I have a text file that contains few paragraphs from a novel. I have read this file into a vector.

fileText = ['Token1,' 'token_2' 'token%!3'] etc.

In this case , _ % ! are the special characters and I would like to replace them with blanks (''). Can this be achieved through regular expressions? I can do this with javascript, but can't get it to work in Matlab.

Thank you

Comment: Can you explain a bit more clearly what you mean ?  Perhaps give us an example ?

Comment: What do you mean by "special characters"?

Comment: Depending on what you meant by "special characters", you might want to use the function ISSTRPROP: http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/isstrprop.html It can test for letters, numbers, spaces, control chars, ...

Comment: Thank you for the replies, pleasee see the edit.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If by "special characters" you mean less-frequently used [Unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) characters like `¥`, `¶`, or `¼`, then you can use either the function [REGEXPREP](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/regexprep.html) or set comparison functions like [ISMEMBER](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/ismember.html) (and you can convert the character string to its equivalent integer code first using the function [DOUBLE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/double.html) if needed). Here are a couple examples where all but the standard English alphabet characters (lower and upper case) are removed from a string:

```
str = ['ABCDEFabcdefÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐ'];   %# A sample string
str = regexprep(str,'[^a-zA-Z]','');      %# Remove characters using regexprep
str(~ismember(str,['A':'Z' 'a':'z'])) = '';  %# Remove characters using ismember
                                             %#   (as suggested by Andrew)
str(~ismember(double(str),[65:90 97:122])) = '';  %# Remove characters based on
                                                  %#   their integer code
```

All of the options above produce the same result:

```
str =

ABCDEFabcdef
```

**EDIT:**

In response to the specific example in the updated question, here's how you can use [REGEXPREP](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/regexprep.html) to replace all characters that *aren't* `a-z`, `A-Z`, or `0-9` with blanks:

```
str = regexprep(str,'[^a-zA-Z0-9]','');
```

This may be easier than trying to write a regex to match each individual "special" character, since there could potentially be many of them. However, if you were *certain* that the only special characters would be `_`, `%`, and `!`, this should achieve the same as the above:

```
str = regexprep(str,'[_%!]','');
```

Also, as mentioned in the comment by [Amro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/97160/amro), you could also use the function [ISSTRPROP](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/isstrprop.html) to replace all non-alphanumeric characters with blanks like so:

```
str(~isstrprop(str,'alphanum')) = '';
```

Comment: +1. Note that 65:122 includes non-alpha characters like [ \ ] `. (Do "disp(char(65:122))" to confirm.) No need to convert to double: ismember() operates characterwise if both inputs are chars and not cellstrs. So "ismember(str, ['A':'Z' 'a':'z'])" works too and IMO is a little more readable than using numeric character codes.

Comment: @Andrew: You're right. I forgot to break the range into parts. Also, good suggestion on using ISMEMBER directly on the character strings. I didn't realize something like `'A':'Z'` would remain a character array instead of being converted automatically to double.

Comment: I think that regexprep is what I'm after. Instead of doing '[A-Za-z]' I built a regexp for all special characters. This didn't work for me. I will run your code in a minute.