# MATLAB Delete strange symbol

Tags: matlab

During reading some strings from a CSV-file, i got some strange symbols (caused by freaky encoding). In the origin, the symbols are invisible. As exmaple:

```
ïfrom
```

Now, I want to clear this string from these artefacts (for further coparison) but `isletter()` does not work. Any ideas?

Comment: Don't have the answer to your question but as a comment, isletter() does not work because ï is actually a letter in French for instance. So your problem is like: how can I detect symbols and letter with accents

Comment: This might solve your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3882609/matlab-how-to-replace-all-the-special-characters-in-a-vector

Comment: The comparison with a "blacklist" of symbols would solve the problem as well. I like [Luis Mendos answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40162129/4667332) more, because it is universal for my purpose and therefore more elegant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to only keep ASCII chars:

```
str = 'ïfrom dañó'; % example
str = str(str<128); % keep only codde points below 128, corresponding to ASCII
```

gives

```
str =
from da
```